# Prove $\mathrm{Re}(z)=0$ if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ of maximum modulus such that $\Big|z+\frac{1}{z}\Big|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima

> let $z$ be a complex number (not lying on $x$-axis) of maximum modulus such that $\Big|z+\dfrac{1}{z}\Big|=1$. Then prove that $\mathcal{Re}(z)=0$

**My Attempt**
$$
|re^{ia}+\frac{1}{r}e^{-ia}|=|\cos a(r+\frac{1}{r})+i\sin a(r-\frac{1}{r})|=1\\
r^2+\frac{1}{r^2}+2\cos 2a=1\implies 2r\frac{dr}{da}-\frac{2}{r^3}\frac{dr}{da}-4\sin 2a=0\\
\frac{dr}{da}.(r-\frac{1}{r^3})=2\sin 2a=0\implies\sin 2a=0\\
a=0\quad\text{or}\quad a=\pi/2\implies a=\pi/2\implies\cos a=0\\
Re(z)=0
$$
Can I prove it without using differentiation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is like this: if $ab \neq 0$, $|a+b| = |a|-|b|$ if and only if $a,b$ make a 180 degree angle when represented geometrically as vectors in the complex plane by the cosine theorem; but now $1 = |z+ \frac{1}{z}| \geq |z|-\frac{1}{|z|}$, so $|z|$ is at most the highest root of $x^2-x-1 = 0$ (which is the golden ratio) and we have equality precisely when $z$ and $\frac{1}{z}$ make a 180 degree angle which is easily seen to be equivalent to $z$ purely imaginary

Comment: how do u say that $|z+\frac{1}{z}|=||z|-|\frac{1}{z}||$ when $|z|$ is maximum ?

Comment: If $|z| = r > 0$ and $1 \geq r - \frac{1}{r}$, then $r^2 - r - 1 \leq 0$ so $r$ is less or equal the positive root of the quadratic by basic algebra

Comment: So u mean
$$
1=|z+\frac{1}{z}|\geq\big||z|-|\frac{1}{z}|\big|\implies|z|^2-|z|-1\leq0
$$
which is a parabola. $f(|z|)\leq0\implies|z|_{max}$ at the roots of $|z|^2-|z|-1=0$.ie. 
$$
|z+\frac{1}{z}|=\big||z|-|\frac{1}{z}|\big|\implies Re\frac{z}{\bar{z}}=\cos(2.\arg z)=-1\implies\arg z=\pi/2\implies Re(z)=0
$$
right ?

Comment: yes, though as noted it's easy to see geometrically by the cosine theorem of elementary geometry that $|a+b| = |a|-|b|$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ (both assumed non-zero of course) make a 180 degree and then since $\arg{\frac{1}{z}} = - \arg z$ (arguments taken from $[-\pi, \pi]$), this forces $z$ to be purely imaginary geometrically too, but you can do it trigonometrically of course if you wish